# sound test doesn't work

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa

The test sound doesn't work in my ubuntu 12.04 in my VAIO SVF14215CLW machine. I tried all suggestions proposed in askubuntu web page, but they don't help to fix the problem.

```
 lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
```

results:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device 90b8
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at c0810000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

and

```
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav
```

results:

```
Playing WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Mono
```

without any sound. Also:

```
 sudo aplay -l
```

gives:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: HDA Generic [HDA Generic]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

any tips would be appreciated.

Farah.

```
Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what solutions you tried as you did not link the post.

Looks like computer has HDMI, have you verified its not using that, rather than your Intel driver? I know on 14.10 its under Sounds. You just need to click the non-hdmi option, if HDMI is selected.

If you have

**Try this:**

```
 sudo killall pulseaudio 
 sudo alsa force-reload
```